# Relation between radius of circles

Tags: geometry, circles

A circle of radius R is given. Inside it there are N  circles of radius r touching circumference of bigger circle.

What is the relation between radius R and r?

Comment: What have you tried?  Have you drawn a picture?  Are centers of the small circles on a circle?  Or do the small circles "fill" the large circle?  The second is hard-look at packomania.

Comment: @RossMillikan -- The OP did say "touching circumference", so it's not packing. But (s)he didn't specify that the small circles touch each other.

Comment: I think, but am not sure, that the OP intends a ring of small circles (radius $r$) which are internally tangent to the big circle.  Thus, the centers of the small circles do indeed lie on a circle (or radius $R-r$) and the centers form a regular $N-$gon with side length $2r$.

Comment: @Ross Millikan  Smaller circles touche each other and they also touch the circumference....they are not packed

Comment: @lulu centre of smaller circles will ofcourse lie on co ceentic circle with centre as of R

Comment: So you agree with the picture I described, yes?  But then the problem is straight forward.  Draw a perpendicular from the center of the big circle to the midpoint of one of the sides of the $N-$gon.  That segment is one leg of a right triangle, with second leg $r$ and hypotenuse $R-r$.  All you need to do is read off one of the angles...

Comment: @lulu Silly me .... thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: inscribedCircles]

The angle between the centers of the small circles is $\frac{2\pi}{n}$(radians), so the angle from one of their centers to their point of tangency is half of that, $\frac{\pi}{n}$. Then

$$\sin\frac\pi n = \frac r x$$
But we don't know what $x$ is yet. We can get it from
$$x + r = R$$
and combine the two equations:
$$x = R - r = \frac{r}{\sin\frac\pi n}$$
$$R = r \left(1 + \frac{1}{\sin\frac\pi n} \right)$$
$$R \sin\frac\pi n = r \left(\sin\frac\pi n + 1 \right)$$

Comment: I got it earlier but thanks